# Facebook Friend Request button element not visible in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, facebook, selenium, selenium-webdriver

> ***`Element` is not Visible***

Trying to send friend requests automatically at Facebook using Python and Selenium

[image: button code...]

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/friends/requests/')
print("Opened facebook...")
email = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='email' and @name='email']")
email.send_keys('')
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='pass' and @name='pass']")
password.send_keys('')
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='loginbutton' and @name='login']")
button.click()
time.sleep(5)
send_friend_request = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='button' and contains(@class,'FriendRequestAdd addButton')]")
send_friend_request.click()
```

The code works till login, `time.sleep(5)` and while running the next codes

```
send_friend_request = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='button' and contains(@class,'FriendRequestAdd addButton')]")
```

It returns error as

> ***Element is not Visible***

Comment: FriendRequestAdd button is same in all facebook pages, add exactly steps and screenshot of screen where you trying locate the button. In your code you try to click button immediately after login and in my page there is no FriendRequestAdd button

Comment: Using any such automation to send friend requests is against Facebook’s ToS to begin with. And has there ever been a reason to send out friend requests in an automated way, that was not spam? I very much doubt it.

Comment: @misorude No I am just having experience and practice of the codes...Less there will be **no** use of sending friend requests to everyone for **any users**...... BIt as I have just attended a workshop on <kbd>Python</kbd> language, I am just having fun with it...

Comment: @sers I didn't understood, what exactly you mean....